# Hide a div in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I'm making a website with flask in python. And I want to hide some divs with the class='alert-warning in the page 4 seconds later the div be loaded. But I have no experience with javaScript so I can not do this.
This is the code of my div:

```
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <div class='alert-warning' id='{{message[:4]}}'>
            <p class="alert-content" id='{{message[:4]}}'>
                {{message}}
            </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So in short I want help to hide the div.alert-waring in four seconds.

Comment: You're on the right track that you need JavaScript for this. So have you searched for "javascript hide div after delay"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using setTimeOut function

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 4000); // Time in milliseconds
```